# trying to print array items on different lines

Tags: java, arraylist

```
enter code here
package Question2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomAlphabets {
//    declaring and initializing Random class for generating random letters.
    Random random = new Random();
    ArrayList<Character> randomCharacters = new ArrayList<>();

//    method to generate Random characters.

    public int generateRandomCharacter(){
        char randomCharacter=0;
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= 16; i++){
            randomCharacter = (char)(random.nextInt(26)+'a');
            randomCharacters.add(randomCharacter );
        }
        return randomCharacter;
    }


//    message to display Random Characters.

    public void displayCharacters() {
        for (int i = 1; i < randomCharacters.size(); i++) {
            if (i % 4 == 0) {
                System.out.println(randomCharacters.get(i));
            } else {
                System.out.print(randomCharacters.get(i) + "|");
            }
        }

        }
    }
```

> i wanted to achieve this output
> w|s|b|e
> h|n|f|f
> y|h|c|t
> l|o|f|g
> but I am getting this output instead
> w|s|b|e
> h|n|f|f
> y|h|c|t
> l|o|f|
> have no idea why I am getting this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this method and try it, the array start at the 0 position:

```
public void displayCharacters() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= randomCharacters.size(); i++) {
        if (i % 4 == 0) {
            System.out.println(randomCharacters.get(i - 1));
        } else {
            System.out.print(randomCharacters.get(i - 1) + "|");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The arraylist index start from 0 in java hence you need to start the loop in displayCharacters method from 0 ,now you might have to tweak your logic for the pattern you want to display.

Comment: i know Umesh, as i didn't to have 0 mod 1 this is the reason i have started my array from 1 .

Comment: You are inserting from 0 and accessing from 1 obviously you will escape 1 element, you can use  if ((i+1) % 4 == 0) and start from 0.

Comment: for(int i = 1 ; i <= 16; i++){
            randomCharacter = (char)(random.nextInt(26)+'a');
            randomCharacters.add(randomCharacter );
        }

Comment: inserting from 1

Comment: You are not using i while inserting in the arraylist , by default elements will be inserted from 0 index , either you use i while inserting or follow my above comment.